# How do the chevrons on engine nacelles reduce noise?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, noise

The B787 has these chevron-shaped teeth on the exhaust port of its engines to reduce noise.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Toothed_exhaust_duct_covers_on_a_Boeing_787.jpg]

And according to the answer to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/119/with-the-upgrade-of-the-737-to-the-max-model-what-major-changes-are-incorporate) they will be incorporated into the new B737's

Can anyone explain how these work to reduce noise?

Comment: Ah, thanks. It's a dupe. Can the [tag:noise] tag be added to the original. I didn't find it.