# Is there any difference between the Boeing 787 and the 737 MAX?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737, boeing-787

I've just done some research on the Boeing 787 and the 737. But the 787 and 737 MAX seem almost completely alike. Are there any differences between the 787 and the 737 MAX?

Comment: Can't help but wondering what "research" you may have done to come to the conclusion that two completely different aircraft are "almost completely alike"!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 787 was a brand new design. The biggest new feature is the extensive use of composite materials throughout the aircraft. The new design also uses electrical systems instead of hydraulic and bleed air systems that are used on most other aircraft. It is a wide-body aircraft, intended to carry large numbers of passengers over long ranges. The new design mostly replaces the older 767 model.

The [737 MAX](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/119/1696) is mostly a re-engine of a very old design. Though much has changed in multiple generations since the original 737 design, it still retains many differences from the 787. The 737 still has the same fuselage cross-section, and the aircraft is still primarily built from aluminum. Aside from fly-by-wire spoilers, hydraulics and bleed air are still used as before. While the new engines on the MAX do have chevrons like those on the 787, they are from a different manufacturer. The other key feature of the MAX, the AT winglets, distinguish it from the 787, with uses much more simple [raked tips](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/19073/1696). The 737 still carries a much lower number of passengers, and is intended for shorter routes.

Answer (score 10):

The main difference is size and purpose. Despite being larger than most 737 variants, the 737-MAX is still a smaller, short haul plane. It carries 180 passengers to the 787's 280, has a range of 3630 nautical miles to the 787s 7635. Above all, the 737-MAX is still a narrow bodied jet, while the 787 is a wide body. All of this means that the 737 MAX is still a smaller jet better tailored to domestic flights, while the 787 is a medium to large jet (depending on the variant) intended for international flying.

Comment: But, other than all that, they're almost completely alike.  Because, you know, Research.